# как вывести название вложенного списка в словарь

Tags: python

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],
    'sarah': ['c'],
    'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
    'phil': ['python', 'haskell']
}

for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():

    if len(languages) < 2:
        print(name.title() + "'s favorite_languages is " + str(languages))
    if len(languages) >= 2:
        print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite_languages are:")
        for language in languages:
            print("\t" + language.title())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вопрос непонятен, кстати в вашем коде надо исправить строку на следующую: `print(name.title() + "'s favorite_languages is " + str(languages[0].title()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему надо что-то вроде этого, но, с таким описанием проблемы, я в этом не уверен:

```
for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():

    if len(languages) < 2:
        print(name.title() + "'s favorite_languages is " + languages[0].title())
    if len(languages) >= 2:
        print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite_languages are:" + '\t'.join(languages).title())
```

Comment: спасибо SergFSM